# ENS nameprep algorigthm. What exactly are the conditions?

Tags: ens, eth-domain

The [documentation of ENS](https://docs.ens.domains/frequently-asked-questions#what-about-foreign-characters-what-about-upper-case-letters-is-any-unicode-character-valid) is not very clear, what exactly are the conditions for registering certain domain names. The recommend following the ENS nameprep algorithm, but I could not find any specifics of what exactly that entails. Can anyone link me to a list of does and dont's or even a documentation of the algorithm itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has reference to the nameprep algorithm:

https://pypi.org/project/ens/0.3.0/

Which reference to a Github repo:

https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-137.md#name-syntax